# Undefined reference to `OGRRegisterAll'

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gdal, ogr

I am trying to write a gdal program to read shapefiles but I don't seem to be able to get past registering the drivers. Here is the code, I'm not sure why the functions in the header files are not available my source file even after including it.

```
#include "/usr/include/gdal/ogrsf_frmts.h"
int main()    
{
   GDALAllRegister();
}
```

If I run this: `g++ demo.cpp`, I get the following error:

```
demo.cpp: In function int main():
demo.cpp:6:21: error: GDALAllRegister was not declared in this scope
 GDALAllRegister();
                 ^
```

If I try the c version, I'm getting this:

```
#include "/usr/include/gdal/ogr_api.h"
int main()
{
    OGRRegisterAll();
    return 0;
}

gcc create.c

/tmp/cc3YB8sO.o: In function main:
create.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to OGRRegisterAll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**UPDATE**
I am using Ubuntu 15.04 64bit
I installed all the packages using the apt:

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev build-essential
```

I also have the ubuntugis ppa added and I have qgis 2.10 installed which is from the qgis repo and not from the ubuntugis ppa.

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you installed GDAL/OGR's libraries? If so - how?

Comment: I think you need to give linker flags

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: the shared libraries that trying to link most probably is not in your path so it cannot link to necessary shared libraries. Try to copy the shared libs to somewhere in class path or reference them with full path.

Comment: Thank you al, the issue was the linker was not able to find the gdal library. i did this gcc create.c -lgdal.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the help, the issue was the linker was not able to find the gdal library. 
i did this for the C code

```
gcc create.c -lgdal
```